# Proof of the valence $\lambda$ of a canonical transformation equaling its Jacobian determinant

Tags: physics, differential-forms

I originally asked this in the Physics SE, but the question was closed because it was not about the underlying physics of it, so I'll try asking here.
Let $Q(q,p),P(q,p)$ be a canonical transformation with valence $\lambda$. The following is intended to be a proof of the following relation:
$$\lambda = \frac{\partial(Q,P)}{\partial(q,p)}.$$
Let $F(q,Q,t)$ be the a generating function of the canonical transformation, which satisfies the following relations:
$$p = \frac{1}{\lambda}\frac{\partial F}{\partial q},\hspace{1em} P = -\frac{\partial F}{\partial Q},\hspace{1em} K = \lambda H + \frac{\partial F}{\partial t},$$
with $K$ the Hamiltonian for the transformed coordinates. From those relations, it is easy to check that its differential is
$$\mathrm{d}F = \lambda \hspace{0.25em}p\hspace{0.25em}\mathrm{d}q - P\hspace{0.25em}\mathrm{d}Q + (K-\lambda H)\hspace{0.25em}\mathrm{d}t$$
and the exterior differential of this is
$$0 = \mathrm{d}^2F = \lambda \hspace{0.25em}\mathrm{d}p\wedge\mathrm{d}q - \mathrm{d}P\wedge\mathrm{d}Q + \mathrm{d}(K-\lambda H)\wedge\mathrm{d}t.$$
I think there is some argument for saying $\mathrm{d}(K-\lambda H)\propto\mathrm{d}t$, and $\mathrm{d}t\wedge\mathrm{d}t = 0$. Rearranging, we would get
$$\mathrm{d}Q\wedge\mathrm{d}P = \lambda\hspace{0.25em}\mathrm{d}q\wedge\mathrm{d}p,$$
and that multiplicative factor must be the Jacobian determinant. QED.

My questions are:

- Is this proof rigorous? It involves manipulating differentials, and we physicists are known for doing that carelessly.
- Is there a simpler or a better-known proof of this? I have tried searched for one, although with no success.

Comment: The "transformation with valence" part is not math, could you give a proper mathematical definition for it? Also Your redaction is not rigorous for mathematics but it surely is for physics, I really think the "colleagues" from Physics SE are wrong, this is a physics topic